# how to insert data into mysql using iphone

Tags: mysql, iphone

I am working on  "MapView" app in iPhone

In this app the Latitude and Longitude of my current Location is send to server so other user can see this Location and display in MapView.

How to insert record or data into mysql(PHP) from iPhone?

Comment: Send the data thru a socket, accept it on the server side and call a sql write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a web server in addition to your database server, to host a web application with an API that your iPhone app can access.  This web app can be written in any language that can write to a MySQL database (php, python, java, ruby, perl, to name a few).  You'll likely want to use a restful api, using json for data representation.  There are many resources available to help you in learning to create such a thing.  Good luck!